# Need to extract substring based on a regex in Python

Tags: python, regex, substring

I need to extract the substring that comes After any possible combination of PO BOX using Python

For e.g.

P.O Box 88743

PO Box 04049

PO BOX 304040

P.O. Box 49293

PO   Box 2039a

result : I should be able to extract following substrngs

88743

4049 (leading 0's removed)

304040

49293

2039a

Substrings can be alphanumeric and contain 1-10 amount of numbers

Please help!!

Answer (score 7):

The following should do it:

```
re.findall(r'P[.]?O[.]?\s*box\s+0*([0-9a-zA-Z]+)', s, re.I)
```

where `s` is your string.